# When does principle of iterated supremum fail?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

When does
$$\text{sup}_{x\in A} \text{sup}_{y\in B}f(x,y) = \text{sup}_{y\in B}\text{sup}_{x\in A} f(x,y)$$
fail?

Further can we also have then that
$$\text{sup}_{x \in A, y\in B} f(x,y)$$
is greater than both of the expressions above?

(By principle of iterated supremum, we need at least that $\text{sup}_{x \in A, y\in B} f(x,y)=\infty$).

Comment: Never for nonempty $A,B$, as long as $f$ takes its values in a set where nonempty subsets have a supremum (such as $[0,\infty]$).

Comment: @Mindlack Okay, but that sounds close to the principle of iterated supremum. I want to see when it fails...